# ExtJS 3.4 - setLoading

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am using ExtJS 3 now, and I really miss setLoading function from ExtJS 4.

Looked throght the docs carefully, did not find it.

How can I set/remove loading state on any component in ExtJS 3.4?

Comment: You should ask your question outright instead of implying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a new LoadMask Object for the component

```
var loadMask = new Ext.LoadMask(cmp, {msg:'Wait message'});
```

and then you can show or hide the mask

```
loadMask.show(); 
loadMAsk.hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a store you could also provide the store as a property for the load mask's config property.  This way you don't have to actually do a hide or show in the store's handler.

```
var store = new Ext.data.Store();
var loadMask = new Ext.LoadMask(cmp, {msg:'Wait message', store: store});
```

from Ext's [LoadMask](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.LoadMask-cfg-store) documentation:

> Optional Store to which the mask is bound. The mask is displayed when a load request is issued, and hidden on either load sucess, or load fail.